# Numerical solving of an ODE including a numerical function itself (matlab, octave)

Tags: matlab, octave

I know this question is a bit vague, but I try to make a simple question out of it.

What I want to do is to solve an ODE numerically with octave. This is, of course, easy if you can just type in the function.

'() = ∇(,) + 1/²

The function (,) is only available as numerical data. Is it possible to solve such an equation with lsode or do I need a more complicated approach?

Is it possible to just do it like this:

```
function xdot = f(x/b, t)
    xdot = a * c(x,t) + 1/x^2;
endfunction

x = lsode("f", x0, (t=linspace(0.01,0.01,5)'));
```

Here, the `linspace` of `t` is the same as used in the numerical solution of the original function. The numerical (differentiated) function is `c(x,t)`, which is just an array.

And `b` is a factor to rescale the array elements to length sizes.

edit: Thank you for helping me with formatting the equation. Well, I've actuall tried it this way and it does not work. The Fortran subroutine doesn't seem to be able to work with this.

Comment: Hi, I don't fully understand your question. What ODE are you trying to solve? The code snippet you've pasted doesn't make sense to me, how can `x/b` be passed as an argument to a function?